# Jquery: getting checkbox values and using them as URL parameters

Tags: jquery, url, checkbox

I have a table with a checkbox column, each checkbox holds a unique value.
Any and all of the checkboxes can be clicked.

When a button is clicked I want to concatenate those values to a URL string that I will then use in an ajax call.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="256">
<input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="317">
<input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="9985">
<input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="3751">
```

This is how I want the URL to end up:

```
http://example.com/data?pid=[checkbox value 1]&pid=[checkbox value 2]&pid=[checkbox value 3]
```

And so on.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
    $(function () {
        var qs = '';
        $('[name="product[]"]').is(':checked').each(function(index, element) {
            qs += "pid=" + element.value + "&";
        });

        console.log(qs);
    });
```

Posting an object would be nicer, but if this is your requirement, this should work. You could trim the final & if you like.

This would be a better solution with posting the data as an array:

```
     $(function() {
        var data = [];
        $('[name="product[]"]').is(':checked').each(function(index, element) {
            data.push(element.value);
        });

        console.log(data);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'your url',
            data: data,
            success: success,
        });
    });
    function success() {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with solution https://jsfiddle.net/15Lx3gvv/

```js
var url = 'http://example.com/data';
$('button').click(function(){
  var first = 0;
  $('input[name="product[]"]').each(function(i){
    if( $(this).is(':checked')){
      url += ((first == 0) ? "?" : "&") + 'pid=' + $(this).attr('value');
      first = 1;
    } 
  });
  console.log(url);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="256">
<input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="317">
<input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="9985">
<input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="3751">

<br/>

<button>
Submit
</button>
```

Whichever `checkbox` is `checked` only those value will be append to the `url`.

Hope this will help you.